# How to render components in react as an outcome of another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I am making a website that has a chatbot on the home page that activates 20 seconds after the home page has loaded . I have also implemented a cookie banner on that website. Now, when the cookie banner is active I don't want the chatbot to load up. But if the visitor has declined or accepted the cookies the chatbot should load up. I am able to implement this logic by implementing a `handleClick` function when the user either accepts or declines cookies. This logic fails when the page reloads because the cookie banner doesn't show up and the `showChatBot` remains `false`. I know this can be achieved by tracking if the cookie banner is shown the chatbot will be hidden and vice versa. But I am not able to track the loading of the cookie banner. The cookie banner and the chat bot are two different components. I am using the `react-cookie-consent` npm package that can be found here : [Link to npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie-consent)

This is the code:

```
const [click, setClick] = useState(false)
  const handleClick = () => {
    setClick(!click)
  }

let showChatBot = true
  if (
    (location && location.pathname.startsWith("*some page*")) ||
    (location && location.pathname.startsWith("*some page*")) ||
    click === false ||
    !location
  ) {
    showChatBot = false
  }
return (
    <Fragment>
          return (
       {showChatBot}
<CookieConsent
          location="top"
          buttonText="Accept"
          enableDeclineButton
          declineButtonText="Decline"
          declineButtonClasses="plain"
          cookieName="gatsby-gdpr-google-analytics"
          onAccept={handleClick}
          onDecline={handleClick}>
                  /*Banner contents*/
</CookieConsent>
)
```

I have used react hooks in my website. Everything is working fine except the part where I don't want to show the chatbot if the cookie banner is active.

Comment: can you show some code ?otherwise it's not easy to debug your code

Comment: The code for the layout is too long but i'll include all the necessary bits.

Comment: If you don't have access to the cookie banner state you can query dom when you are about to show the chat, check if the cookie banner is present and decide if you need to keep waiting